# how to insert the values to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

[[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcqzb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSTLP.png)

I can't insert the values to mysql database

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect. MySQL5InnoDBDialect
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]

Comment: That should be in the hibernate core jar, which should be on your classpath

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: And also please provide details about your problem. Just posting the error message can't help